# Does precession affect loss of angular velocity in collisions?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, collision, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity, precession

I'm a higher schooler trying to do a project on how moment of inertia affects loss of angular velocity in spinning top collisions.

Right now, I'm trying to find factors that might affect my results beyond just moment of inertia, and my teacher recommended I talk about precession. I did a bit of research online though and I can't really see how precession would affect the loss of angular velocity. So can someone explain if it does affect collisions, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a significant external torques, one might expect that angular momentum would be conserved in the short period of time associated with a collision.  In a collision, one object may gain angular momentum (relative to a chosen reference point) at the expense of the other. The amount transferred will depend on the nature of the contact force. Since there is an angular momentum vector associated with the precession of an object, that may play a part. (With several variables and unknowns, including 3D vectors, the collision of spinning tops does not strike me as a fruitful area of study for a high school student.)